# Scala, Exercise with recursive function

Tags: scala

Trying to solve the exercises in the book "Scala for the Impatient", I have a little problem. (Below are my solutions)

1: Write a for loop for computing the product of the Unicode codes of all letters in a string. For example, the product of the characters in "Hello" is 825152896

```
    var p = 1; val S = "Hello"                          
    for (i <- S) p*= i
    println(p)
```

2: Solve the preceding exercise without writing a loop. (Hint: look at the String0ps Scaladoc.)

```
    val St="Hello".map(_.toInt).product ; println(St)
```

3: Write a function product(s : String) that computes the product, as described in the preceding exercises.

```
    def product(s: String)={
      val S=s; println(S.map(_.toInt).product)
    }
    product("Hello")
```

1. Make the function of the preceding exercise a recursive function.

   ```
   ??? I do not know how to do it
   ```

I hope that someone can help me. 
Best regards, 
Francesco

Comment: a recursive function is a function that invokes itself, but checks for termination condition before doing that to avoid infinite recursion. To calculate a product recursively you will need to implement a function similar to `fold` function in functional languages, and pass 1 as the initial value of the accumulator, and the string. The function then will check if string is empty and call itself with the tail of the string, and the adjusted accumulator, if not. Upon termination, the value of the accumulator is the result.

Answer (score 0):

Using well-known recursive functions and modifying them to comply with a different problem may prove quite a helpful approach.

Consider as a start-up pattern the factorial recursive function,

```
def factorial(n: Int): Int = 
  if (n <= 1) 1 else n * factorial (n-1)
```

Consider now the factorial recursive function where the input is assumed to be a list of integers from 1 to n, and so note the way the input list is reduced to the base case,

```
def factorial(xs: List[Int]): Int = 
  if (xs.isEmpty) 1 else xs.head * factorial (xs.tail)
```

This transformation is now closer to a solution for the original problem on string input.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I solved with:

```
def prodRec(s: String): Int = {
    var s2 =s.toList
    if (s2.isEmpty) 1 
    else {
      s2.head * prodRec (s.tail)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. Does not even work in this way. 
I'm still looking for some hint.

Answer (score 0):

Ok...finally my code works:

```
def prodRec(s: String): Int = { 
    if (s.toList.isEmpty) 1     
    else {                  
      s.toList.head * prodRec(s.tail)
    }
}
println(prodRec("Hello"))
```

I hope that this code snippet might help someone else...
best regards
francesco

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of writing the recursive solution to the product:

```
def getProduct(s: String):Int = {

    def accumulate(acc:Int,ch:Array[Char]):Int = {
        ch.headOption match {
            case None => acc
            case Some(x) => accumulate(acc*x.toInt,ch.tail)
        }
    }
    accumulate(1,s.toArray)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My variant of tail recursive function. No vars used, which is a plus.

```
  def product(s: String): Unit = {
    @tailrec
    def help(z: Long, array: Array[Char]): Long = {
      if (array.isEmpty) z else help(z * array.head.toInt, array.tail)
    }
    print(help(1L, s.toCharArray))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def product (s:String): Long ={
  if (s.length==1) s(0) else s.head * s.product (s.tail)
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't as helpful as code with explanatory text. And with a question as old as this one, with so many answers already, it is especially helpful to point out how your answer is different from any/all preceding answers.